# Query xml file by attribute in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-2.0

How could I query an xml file, like the one below, with C# .NET 2.0? I have the id value and need to get the thumbnail image related to that id.

```
<root>
    <categories>
        <category title="decking">
            <photos>
                <photo id="1" smallphoto="/files/images/photogallery/thumbs/EarthwoodEvolutions1_thumb.jpg"  />
                <photo id="2" smallphoto="/files/images/photo-gallery/thumbs/XLM401_thumb.jpg"  />
            </photos>
        </category>
    </categories>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XmlDocument

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

And look up the desired nodes using xpaths.

For your case something like:

```
root/categories/category/photos/photo[@id='1']
```

Comment: Thanks so simple but always forget the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and [`SelectNodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx), e.g.:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();  
doc.Load(xmlFilename);

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/root/categories/category/photos/photo[@id='" + photoId + "']");
XmlNode photoNode = nodes.Item(0);
// Use thumbnail in photoNode.Attributes["smallphoto"].InnerText
```